# How can I type Russian characters with accents in KDE?

Tags: kde, keyboard-layout, unicode, input-method, kate

I use KDE and have enabled the Russian keyboard layout. This works fine except that I see no opportunity to add accents to vowels. Is this in fact possible? I wish to use them in applications such as Kate (which uses Unicode/UTF-8 for my document), to mark accented syllables to aid my pronunciation. The help for System Settings - Keyboard talks about levels of keys, but does not say what that means.

I would have expected there to be a dead key for the accent, but cannot find one. If necessary I would be prepared to edit configuration files, but it seems to me unlikely that that would be necessary.

I have my keyboard model set to generic 101-key PC,and my keyboard is a Dell model SK-8115, attached via USB to an Acer laptop. My Linux is Open Suse Leap 15.1 with the latest updates.

#### Updates

2020-04-10: Though I feared it might be off-topic there, I have asked a duplicate in Russian SE:

- https://russian.stackexchange.com/questions/22334/how-can-i-type-russian-characters-with-accents-in-kde

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For that purpose I've been using a different Russian layout, called "Russian (with Ukrainian-Belorussian layout)"; in Cinnamon's keyboard settings I had to tick a checkbox that shows less common layouts in the layout selection, but I'm confident those are also available on other DEs like KDE. That layout is mostly the same apart from some symbols, and you can make accents pressing Alt Gr + ё (well, the key that would produce ë on the standard layout) after the letter that you want to have an accent. (Normal ë is then done by pressing Alt Gr + e)

I only need accents when I add vocabulary in Anki, so I have both the standard layout and the Ukrainian-Belorussian layout in my list and switch between them according to my needs.

Comment: Thanks, that is available in KDE Keyboard layouts and it works for me. This is useful, and there are some amazing things in there with Alt-Gr, as far as I can see: ‘¡²³¤€¼½¾‘’¥×’ ‘јҵўқёњґҡԅӡһї\’ ‘ѳіԝәԥҁөљџђє’ ‘ѩћѭ×ѵҭҥ«»…’  – not just the combining accent, also Russian quotes, Yen, ellipsis, fractions, … though what I thought was Plank’s constant is evidently Serbo-Croatian! And apart from ё and «№» (Shift+«3») → «§», everything in the usual place.

Comment: These days I see that the layout I use is called “Russian (Polyglot and Reactionary)”. I am not sure if this is the same, but I think not, because I get the combining accent as ``AltGr``+`; ё is ``AltGr``+``е`` (where Cyrillic ``е`` is ``t`` in the US International layout). This is a similarly comprehensive layout with up to 8 characters per key, obtained by combinations of ``Shift``, ``Alt Gr`` and ``Alt Windows``, where the last 2 should be specified under System Settings — Keyboard — Advanced — Key to select the 3rd|5th level.

Answer (score 1):

For Russian, use the "Combining Acute" feature (U+0301) as there are not specific characters for the Russian vowels with accents.  I map the combining acute this to my backtick/tilde key as when I'm writing Russian, I'm typically not programming and don't need the backtick.  (but you could map it anywhere you like).  To type a "ы́" you simply type "ы" and then hit the "Combining Acute" key.

I have put the project "russian-keyboardlayout-with-accents" on github to demo my current setup. (Mileage may vary)

Distributions can be slightly different, but on Debian/Ubuntu, add this line to the setup you care to edit in /usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/ru

key <TLDE> { [ 0x01000301, tilde ] };

Once I edit this I delete/readd my keyboard layout in xfce as it seems to be the most seamless workflow for my setup.

Comment: Thanks a lot; this is very useful, clarifies much and I shall mark it as accepted if it works for me. I am also in the process of asking a question about inspecting Unicode / UTF-8 files.

Comment: My new question is https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/593273/how-can-i-examine-the-unicode-encoding-of-a-text-document .

Comment: I fear that I have accepted a different answer, which points to a different keyboard layout which already maps the combining accent. That approach is a lot simpler and easier to pass on to others. (P.S. You did not include a link to your github project, at https://github.com/jamega/russian-keyboardlayout-with-accents ).